# How to convert tensorflow saved_model to ckpt?

Tags: tensorflow, model, converters

I only have the API that accepts a `ckpt` folder but the pre-trained model is given in `saved_model` format. Is there any methods to convert `saved_model` to `ckpt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out:

Under TensorFlow 1.15:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    imported = tf.saved_model.load(
        sess, ["serve"], "${saved_model_path}")
    saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=1)
    saver.save(sess, "${model_name}.ckpt")
```